# Nonlinear manifold learning and distances between projected points

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, nonlinear, euclidean, manifold-learning

If I use a manifold learning method to project some data points into a low dimensional space, what will be the distances between the projected points? Can I use Euclidean distance? If the distances will not be Euclidean, what kind of distance metric do I have to use and how?

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the manifold learning technique, I think.

[DrLIM](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf), for instance is Euclidean, but I've seen other metrics.  Section 6 of [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/reluICML.pdf) used cosine distance, and I've seen Hamming distance as well.

Which method did you have in mind?

Comment: I wanted to use http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI10/paper/view/1924.

Comment: @Hossein Equation 2 seems to suggest that they're using Euclidean distance, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That norm is because of this : "Each point of an n-dimensional manifold has a neighbourhood that is homeomorphic to the Euclidean space of dimension n.", -from wikipedia!